# Pycord - how to make SubCommands or SlashCommands Groups?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

Can you tell me if there is a way to create subcommands or groups of slashcommands?
I found on the docs [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/bridge/api.html#discord.ext.bridge.BridgeCommandGroup) this: "class discord.ext.bridge.BridgeCommandGroup(callback, *args, **kwargs)" but I do not understand how to use it. Do you have an example for me?
Thank you!

My goal was to create a command
/ticket
command with the following subcommands:
/ticket open
/ticket close
/ticket config
/ticket add_person

but for the moment I made a SlashCommand for each command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The class you've mentioned, `BridgeCommandGroup`, appears to be a class that allows running both traditional and slash commands in the same function. Slash Command Groups are somewhat an entirely separate matter, as they do not allow execution of traditional commands from its collection of slash commands.

For your main question, Slash Command Groups can be made inside a Cog file or in your main bot file.

Slash Command Groups are fairly simple to implement in PyCord.

In Main Bot File

```
bot = discord.Bot()
foo = bot.create_group("foo", "This does something...")

bot.add_application_command(foo) #add the group of functions to the bot
```

In Cog Class:

```
#in the class "Baz"
bar = discord.SlashCommandGroup("bar", "This does something else...")

@bar.command(name="ping") #assign the command under the SlashCommandGroup
async def ping(self, ctx):
    await ctx.respond("pong")

#outside Cog class
bot.add_cog(Baz(bot))
```

This sample shows creating instances of Slash Command Groups. As for subgroups, they can be implemented from the main Slash Command Groups themselves.

```
foo = discord.SlashCommandGroup("foo", "Group 1")
bar = foo.create_subgroup("bar", "Group 2 of Group 1")
# the bar group gets assigned under foo, our first slash command group
```

---

More information on creating slash commands can be found in the docs.

[create_group()](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.create_group)

[discord.SlashCommandGroup](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/application_commands.html#discord.SlashCommandGroup)